# SQL eventdata()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

when using a trigger in SQL SERVER 2005 the eventdata() always return a empty value.

only the date inserted in the Audit table, other fields are NULL valus

pls help me

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TrigDip]
   ON  [dbo].[Dip]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @ed XML
SET @ed = EVENTDATA()

DECLARE @db varchar(1000)

set @db =EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
PRINT 'CREATE TABLE Issued.'

INSERT INTO Audit (PostTime, DatabaseName, Event, ObjectName, TSQL, Login) 
VALUES
(
    GetDate(),
    @db,              
    EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
    EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)'),
    CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER)
) 

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EVENTDATA on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) states

> EVENTDATA returns data only when referenced directly inside of a DDL or logon trigger. EVENTDATA returns null if it is called by other routines, even if those routines are called by a DDL or logon trigger.

Your trigger above is a DML AFTER trigger.

You need

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_CreateTable
ON DATABASE 
FOR CREATE_TABLE 
...
```

Comment: Ok I got It thanks and please give me a sample for  DML AFTER trigger where i can get the changed value of a table data

Comment: @CIYRUS@ look at CREATE TRIGGER http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx It is all explained there: the difference between DML and DDL triggers